# Preventing Image Caching, but can't get image width

Tags: jquery, html, mobile

I tried to preventing image caching with adding some string in img tag like

```
<img src="<?php echo $r['url']."?s=".time()?>" id="images-content"/>
```

Before I adding some string to img tag, I can get width and height image using this

```
var image = $("#images-content");
var width = image[0].naturalWidth;
var height = image[0].naturalHeight;
```

After adding some string it's always return 0 for width or height. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to allow for the image to load

```
$("#images-content").on('load', function(){
    var width = this.naturalWidth;
    var height = this.naturalHeight;
});
```

Comment: It's work for me, thanks.